# Nested foreach loop for Drupal module

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, foreach, drupal-7

I want to parse the array and want to get `sid` value from the array. I have traced using foreach as given below. I caught a warning message in second foreach loop in Drupal module. How to add

```
foreach($submission as $sub) {
  foreach($sub as $a) { // Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 
    if (isset($a[1])) {
      $sid = $a[1]->sid;
    }
  }
}
```

`$submission` value:

```
 Array
 (
   [build_info] =>

Array
(
    [args] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [sid] => 176
                    [nid] => 2
                    [submitted] => 1522130239
                    [remote_addr] => ::1
                    [uid] => 1
                    [name] => admin
                    [is_draft] => 0
                )

        )
)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand from your snippet it rather should be the following:

```
$sid = $submission['build_info']['args'][1]->sid;
```

Or if you prefer it in an foreach loop:

```
foreach ($submission['build_info']['args'] as $key => $args) {
  $sid = isset($args->sid) ? $args->sid : NULL;
}
```